# Automatically generating Level of Detail information

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js, frame-rate

I have a very simple but large scene containing lots of objects and a lot of these objects are small but curved objects so they have large polygon counts. The FPS on the scene is really horrible. I learned that a Level of Detail optimization should help alot.

I am using three.js and it has an option to set LOD. But the model, doesn't have any LOD information (alternate meshes for each object corresponding to distance from the object). Is there something like a tool to generate this information by automatically by decimating the original mesh to create the alternate meshes?

But I can't imagine how textures will be skinned on the decimated meshes. Do I have to manually create the LOD information? 3D editors like Blender, 3dsMax, Unity editor let me set these meshes up individually. But I have about 200 meshes in my scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level of Detail information can not be generally generated automatically. And yes it a painstaking process to create the LOD info. You can look at the [LOD Book](http://lodbook.com/) site for help.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to this question is actually not quite correct anymore.

While it's true that it's a painstaking process to create LOD data it gets easy when using InstaLOD. [InstaLOD](http://www.InstaLOD.io) is a fully automatic 3d optimization solution that's able to optimize any static and skeletal mesh and maintain all vertex attributes like texture coordinates. Besides the polygon optimization, InstaLOD also features remeshing, occlusion culling, imposter creation and other unique methods related to the optimization of individual 3D models and complex scenes.

*DISCLAIMER: I am one of the devs of InstaLOD.*

Comment: Seems like the accepted is correct or was correct in 2014, when InstaLOD did not exist.

Comment: That is a good point. I've modified the first sentence. Thanks for the hint!